# doxygen index C functions

Tags: c, function, indexing, doxygen

How can I index the C functions for the search engine? E.g. I have the following piece of code documented.

```
/**
.... 
* @defgroup MyGroup
*
* @{
*/

/**
* Initialize TCN.
...
*/
int myfunction(void);
...
```

The myfunction is documented on the HTML under MyGroup. With the search engine I get only the structures not the functions. I'm using the client search engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comment style, you could try to use `JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF = YES` to have doxygen interpret the first line within a comment header as a brief description.

You can also set `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` to have doxygen behave as if all functions are documented even if no documentation is available. It will extract all functions except private class members.

To also include private class members include `EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES`

Good luck.

Comment: They are already set. In fact the HTML is complete. But I cannot find the functions using the local search engine. Thanks

Comment: OK, so you are viewing the documents that have been generated and the search function isn't finding one of your functions? If so are your files being served by a web server or are you browsing them on your local filesystem in a browser? They require javascript enabled on a actual server to provide the search box and incremental search tips. If you are on your local filesys, the little drop box will let you check all, functions, etc.., but the search field will not take input or give results. It will work fine on apache or the like.